# Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform - Sync-Unicorn fails

Tags: unicorn, habitathome

While I'm trying to install `Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform`, I'm getting `Unicorn Sync` issue.

1. I did install `Sitecore XP Single v9.2 using SIF`.
2. I verified the installation by logging in to Sitecore and accessing the homepage
3. I did update the `cake-config.json`
4. I run the `build.ps1` file
5. Below is the issue

`Sync-Unicorn
    ========================================
    Sync Unicorn items from url: https://habitathome.dev.local/unicorn.aspx
    Executing: &"C:/Projects/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform/scripts/Unicorn/Sync.ps1" -secret 749CABBC85EAD20CE55E2C6066F1BE375D2115696C8A8B24DB6ED1FD60613086 -url https://habitathome.dev.local/unicorn.aspx <br>
    Cake.exe : An error occurred when executing task 'Sync-Unicorn'.
    At C:\Projects\Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform\build.ps1:251 char:1
    + &$CAKE_EXE $cakeArguments
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (An error occurr...'Sync-Unicorn'.:String) [], RemoteException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

    Error:  One or more errors occurred. 
    The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. 
    PS C:\Projects\Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform>`

6. After this error, when I try to login I'm getting this error.

[image]

Does anybody has a solution for this issue?

Comment: Have you installed SPE and SXA 1.9 as well? They are also prerequisites for this demo on Sitecore 9.2.

Comment: A common issue i see with that sample is that ppl will use Sitecore.Habitathome.Utilities project's main install steps but do not install the modules correctly.  There is install-modules.ps1 that needs to be ran.

Comment: Honestly, the documentation was not clear. So I did not install SXA. I thought Unicorn Serialization will first install the required modules. I will install SXA and retry it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did delete my failed installation, including SQL databases, IIS sites, root folders, and services. I did start from scratch.
1. I did install Sitecore v9.2 utilizing SIF
2. I did install "Sitecore PowerShell Extension 5.0" for Sitecore 9.2
3. Then I did install Sitecore SXA 1.9
4. The last step was to Sync Unicorn which worked without any issues.

There were a few prerequisites that I had to verify and install which I did not mention. It is really important to read and follow the instructions and not skip any prerequisites.